# Accessing custom block fields from a template file

Tags: theming, blocks

I have a sidebar region "Sidebar Ad" and placed in that region is the custom block "Sidebar Ad" of type "Image" which has two fields "Image" and "Link".

When I output the block on my page using `{{ page.sidebar_ad }}`, I get the image and the link separate from each other, which is to be expected. What I can't figure out, and I've been trying for around 5 hours now, is how to reference the fields separately so I can wrap the link around the image.

Does anyone know how to reference those fields? Am I going about this the wrong way?

I've successfully pulled the link URL by overriding the specific block template and referencing:

```
{% block content %}
        <a href="{{ content.field_link.0['#url'].uri }}"></a>
{% endblock %}
```

Referencing the image URL still eludes me.

Comment: You say to put field image inside of link field?

Comment: When I do that it keeps the image header on top of the image. I could remove it with styling but I'd prefer to bypass it altogether if possible.

Answer (score 1):

This was the final solution.

```
{% block content %}
    <a href="{{ content.field_link.0['#url'].uri }}">
        <img src="{{ file_url(content.field_image.0['#item'].entity.fileuri) }}" alt="{{ content.field_image.0['#item'].alt }}">
    </a>
{% endblock %}
```